# python program flow (no gui) command line

Tags: python, list, lines

I there easy a way to list all **executed** lines from a python program on command level ?

I am running a python program with while statement included but cannot find out what lines are executed.

I am running on a RPI command window through putty

Comment: [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).

Comment: You can use [`sys.setrace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html?highlight=settrace#sys.settrace) to set up something that will do this.

Comment: Thanks, gone try it out.